# why Fiddler4 not support Content-Type 'application/x-protobuf'?

Tags: fiddler

Both request/response not showing proper formatted text
[Image show info on fiddler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRmNE.png)

[example x-protobuf data not showing proper formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRglH.png)

[example x-protobuf data not showing proper formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASNXv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler do not has no support for Protobuf encoded messages. If you want't to know why that can't be answered here - contact Telerik and ask them.

There is an old plugin for Fiddler named [ProtoMiddler](https://github.com/JonathanJoelBoyd/ProtoMiddler) that extends Fiddler to have some basic protobuf support, however it is quite complicated to install as it relies on protobuf installed (AFAIR the old protobuf v2) into a certain absolute path and the plugin has not been updated for years.

If you really need a Proxy with good Protobuf support I can only recommend Charles proxy to you. It allows to view protobuf messages RAW as well as decoded using compiled protobuf definitions (can be loaded/updated at run-time). Furthermore you can assign protobuf definitions to certain request and/or response paths.

Comment: Thanks..ProtoMiddler is old not properly support x-protobuf. I have requested to Telerik add x-protobuf feature in upcoming update in fiddler

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, Fiddler doesn't support Protobuf.

If you need the see qualified Protobuf content, you need a schema that generates a protobuf binary.

You can try out Charles Proxy or [Proxyman](https://docs.proxyman.io/advanced-features/protobuf). They both support Protobuf parser pretty well.